# How to keep stdin and stdout separated when printing output?

Tags: c, shell, unix, stdout, stdin

Consider the following code which outputs some text every few seconds:

```
int main (void)
{
    int status = 0;
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            printf ("whatever...\n");
            // printf ("\rwhatever...\n");
            sleep (3);
        }
    }
    while (wait (&status) > 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem i'm having is that if i have some text already typed in the terminal, the outputed text would be added to the end of the input buffer like:

```
> whatever...
< something
> somethingwhatever...
<
```

How can I make it print the output buffer and keep the input buffer intact at the same time like:

```
> whatever...
< something
> whatever...
< something
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use some inter-process locking mechanism (such as a semaphore).

Comment: That is not trivial and requires more information on how your program handles input. Are you using things like readline? scanf? std::cin?

Comment: The streams are not mixed. It is your console-output. Disable echo and print input & output in sequence.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I'm creating a command-like interface and want to use readline to read the input.

Comment: The other way is to use pipes and launch executable like `cat input.file | appname > output.file`. Or some kind of workarounds to split input and output to different terminals.

Comment: @SergeyKanaev: I did not intend to list **all** possible solutions nor start a discussion. There are already comments stating the underlying problem; leave it to OP to implement one. Untel then the question is OT.

Comment: For the output to different terminals, you might be able to output to different `tty`s. Maybe something like `myprog > /dev/tty2`

Comment: @Olaf can you please provide an answer on how to do that?

Comment: @razzak: I will not. Because your question lacks information and any comprehensive answer would be too long for this site. You got some keywords so you can dig yourself. You will need this knowledge anyway, so please learn fishing, not just how to eat a fish.

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on the standard I/O handling provided by the terminal, you have no control over this aspect.

What you can do is take care of this manually. You can either separate input and output into two columns using `tput` or `ncurses`, or you can turn off input echoing (input will not be displayed) and display the input yourself.

The problem with the second approach is that it will most likely be confusing for the user.